Do reductive materialists believe that consciousness is "reducible in principle" to the Standard Model of particle physics?
From Wikipedia:

The Standard Model of particle physics is the theory describing three of the four known fundamental forces (electromagnetic, weak and strong interactions – excluding gravity) in the universe and classifying all known elementary particles. It was developed in stages throughout the latter half of the 20th century, through the work of many scientists worldwide,[1] with the current formulation being finalized in the mid-1970s upon experimental confirmation of the existence of quarks. Since then, proof of the top quark (1995), the tau neutrino (2000), and the Higgs boson (2012) have added further credence to the Standard Model. In addition, the Standard Model has predicted various properties of weak neutral currents and the W and Z bosons with great accuracy.

One might argue, for instance, that chemistry is reducible in principle to physics. Similarly, if we consider the Standard Model of particle physics a reasonable framework for describing the physics governing the particles that constitute a brain, would most reductive materialists agree that consciousness is, in principle, reducible to the equations of the Standard Model? Could the equations of the Standard Model, in principle, predict that a particular arrangement of particles (X) is conscious while another arrangement (Y) is not conscious?

You're asking a lot of questions about reducing consciousness to other disciplines. As I said in another question, we don't really understand consciousness well and there are no good answers.

IMHO, consciousness is most likely an emergent phenomenon. Reducing it to physics, mathematics, etc. won't be very enlightening.

Using the SM to explain consciousness would be like using quantum mechanics to predict the weather, or even something simple like the trajectory of a billiard ball.

@Barmar It looks like you completely ignored the in principle qualifier (and you also completely ignored the referenced answer that further elaborates on this distinction).

You ask:

Do reductive materialists believe that consciousness is "reducible in principle" to the Standard Model of particle physics?

And then:

Could the equations of the Standard Model, in principle, predict that a particular arrangement of particles (X) is conscious while another arrangement (Y) is not conscious?

These are two different questions.
To address the first: reductive materialists do not have a commitment to today's current model of physics. Rather, their position is that any observable phenomenon is reducible to physics, in whatever incarnation that actually consists of.
To address the second: maybe, but that is a totally separate question than whether consciousness is reducible, let alone whether it is reducible to today's model(s) of physics.
